# how can a program login to a website having a html form for username and password

Tags: php, pear

I need to scrape from a website that requires authentication, that is a user must login by supplying there username and password in an html form. The connection is not secure. I plan on using the [Pear framework](http://pear.php.net/) to format the request. I'm stuck at the first part which is posting the login information. How can I submit form data? Thanks in advance for any help.

I've got fiddler2 installed but am not sure what to look for when I do the login manually.

I'm using curl and getting some success. I deleted all cookies in my web browser and went to the site to login. In fiddler it gave me the following request headers

```
GET http://example.com/niceday/dirlogin.php HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-CA
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: example.com
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: chatRoomUserID=119972; ASPSESSIONIDSSRQCCBR=26jqrt3f8dus2l2s42g4r9npp5
```

I'm confused about the last one, am I requesting a cookie?

In my script I faked the first request with

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('GET http://example.com/niceday      /dirlogin.php     HTTP/1.1',
'Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*',
'Referer: http://r2sports.bkoehler.j43.ca/tourney/tourneyTop.php?TID=3206',
'Accept-Language: en-CA',
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)',
'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
'Connection: Keep-Alive',
'DNT: 1',
'Host: r2sports.bkoehler.j43.ca',
'Cookie: chatRoomUserID=995222; ASPSESSIONIDSSRQCCBR=26jqrt3f8dus2l2s42g4r9npp5'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php#90821 and setting a cookie file location, so your script can remain authenticated. Next time it will contact that website it will use the cookies it previously saved in a file in the cookie file location.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I submit form data?

Here is how:

```
<form action="./login.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" />
<input type="password" name="password" />
</form>
```

Use login.php to process your $_POST data.

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to do :) I want '$request = new HTTP_Request2('http://www.example.com/secret.php', HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);' but you have to login before your allowed to view the page.